# Are $f \in o(1)$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(n) = 0$ equivalent when $f\geq 0$?

Tags: real-analysis

Given a function $f: \mathbb{N} \to [0, \infty]$, Is $f \in o(1)$ equivalent to $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(n) = 0$?

My reason is that $f \in o(1)$ means that $\forall k >0$, there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $f(n) \leq k$ for all $n\geq n_0$. That is the same as $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(n) = 0$.
Thanks!

Comment: Yes - there's nothing wrong with that reasoning, and I'm happy to see you used $f\in o(1)$ instead of $f = o(1).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the usual definition, $f(n) \in o(g(n))$ if $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists n_0 \forall n > n_0 \colon \lvert f(n) \rvert \le \epsilon \cdot g(n)$. In your specific case ($g(n) = 1$) this is $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists n_0 \forall n > n_0 \colon \lvert f(n) \rvert \le \epsilon$, which can easily be seen to be equivalent to $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n) = 0$.